# Method is "Post" in Chrome/Firefox Network dev tool but "Get" in PHP request method

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, request

Method is "POST" in Google and Firefox "Network" dev tool
but when I checked it in PHP it's empty..

Error

```
Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\myecommerse\includes\detailsmodal.php on line 39
```

Button

```
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-small btn-success" onclick="detailsmodal(<?php echo $product['id']; ?>)">Details</button>
```

PHP

```
 if (empty ($_POST['id'])) {
    echo "empty";
}
else
{
     echo "full";
}

?>
```

Ajax

```
 function detailsmodal(id){
        var data = {"id" : id}; //Json string 
        jQuery.ajax({
                url: "./includes/detailsmodal.php",
                type: "POST",   
                data: data,
                success : function(data){
                    jQuery('body').append(data);
                    jQuery('#details-modal').modal('toggle'); 
                },
                error : function(){
                    alert('something went wrong');
                }

        });

    }
```

Thanks in advance for those who'll answer..im just new  in using ajax

Comment: Try with `{id:id}` just suggestion or check alert(Id); getting id or not

Comment: Maybe you have a redirection implemented on the server side?

Comment: @arkascha what do you mean about that? in .htaccess?

Comment: Either in the real http servers host configuration of in a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess"), yep.

Comment: @arkascha i got it now but when i click the function for the 1st "id" its working but when i click the second button to call the same function with a different "id".. its going to use the "id" of the first button,..,how can i solve that bro?\

Comment: Which appears to be a completely new question. You mentioned none of all this in your question above...

Comment: @arkascha it is.. i cant find a thread to this question..